# JQuery Click on an input which contains a certain value

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery I am looking for a way to Click on an Input which contains a certain value.

```
For example:

<input type="button" class="myclass" value="one" />
<input type="button" class="myclass" value="two" />
```

How can I get JQuery to click on the button that contains the value of "two" for example?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to trigger the click event for the element that contains this value ?

Comment: Yes, I need jquery to click on the one with the value of "two"

Comment: hey check out is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/TMPet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$('input.myclass[value="two"]').click();
```

or

```
$('input.myclass[value="two"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: @user3127499 My office's brainless security system blocking me to create a fiddle.. sorry.. But this should work..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ignore him - he's not even the OP.  +1 for right answer.

Comment: @Archer it was a good question and he was the first to give an answer and i was not trolling just wanted to know more about it and by the way what's OP

Comment: @user3127499 OP means "original poster" or "original post" (the question asker, or the question) - it depends on the context.  Also, if you want a demo then simply create one yourself at http://jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input.myclass[type="button"][value="two"]').click(function(){

});
```

or

```
$('input.myclass[type="button"][value="two"]').trigger('click');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/LP35Y/)

Comment: He wants to trigger a click, not handle one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('input.myclass[value="two"]').click(); // programmatically clicked


$('input.myclass[value="two"]').click(function(){  // event handler for click

alert('clicked');

});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3KgJ2/)